# SASS map values are different when looped over

Tags: sass

I have two lists `("box-shadow", "label-and-field--box-shadow"), ("border", "label-and-field--border")` (shown by a `@debug` directive on my variable).
SASS tells me that both are of type `list` via `type-of`.
They seem to have the same syntax...and however... when I do an `@each $property-to-theme in $properties-to-theme` on this thing, I get two different kind of things for `$property-to-theme`  :
`"box-shadow", "label-and-field--box-shadow"` and `("border", "label-and-field--border")`

Why it is no more the same thing ? Either it should have parentheses on the first list too or it should not have parentheses on the second list!

In case some do not understand what could happen because of this inconsistency... If I use `list.length` on the items, when we have parentheses it gives `1`, without it gives `2`.

I have one condition that uses this length so my code cannot work.

I am using SCSS with SASS 1.27.0 compiled with dart2js 2.10.1.

**Edit**

I have tested to copy the debug output in a variable $test doing :

```
$test : ("box-shadow", "label-and-field--box-shadow"), ("border", "label-and-field--border");
```

and it works as expected for this variable! So why ...
`("box-shadow", "label-and-field--box-shadow"), ("border", "label-and-field--border")`
is different from
`("box-shadow", "label-and-field--box-shadow"), ("border", "label-and-field--border")`
?!

Comment: As I tested the result ist with/without brackets the same. Could you provide an example of code wich results the difference ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I work on this difference because I do not see other difference between two scenarios and however ...one scenario work and the other do not...and they have been coded exactly the same way. I think I will lose my mind on this. The whole thing represents a lot of code and the library is not, actually, open source so I put only the thing that I believe responsible of my problem. Maybe it is not :(

Comment: To your Edit: to be honest ... I cannot see any difference between the three variables notations ... to make it sure checking in editor also says: 3 time exactly same code ... ;-(  ## Additional: to explain the issue additonal the `@each` loop (or example) would be very helpful to see and test what the difference is you mean.